# How to color vertices of cube

Tags: vertex-colors, vector-mapping

I am trying to color the vertex points of a octahedron and want to have control over how they blend into each other.
I am using a mapping node but am not able to achieve the desired result.

The image below shows the desired effect, however it was created with lights.

[image]

Comment: To have something similar to bottom pic requires much densier mesh then default cube.

Comment: Maybe use a shader, mapping object-space XYZ to RGB as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133827/35559)?

Comment: The effect you want is nearly what is shown in the answer below (as the final result may depend on world global light intensity). Or a variation on it or using object texture coordinates as suggested by @RobinBetts. So what do you expect exactly, and in particular about "controlling" the colors?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your UV mapping is off; using a similar setup and a default cube, I'm getting this result:

[image]

You can also achieve what you're trying to do using vertex colors:

[image]

Also see: [How can vertex paint be rendered?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/how-can-vertex-paint-be-rendered)

Comment: hey bryan: what do you mean with my UV mapping is off? And how do I fix it?